# Most advanced scientific calculator (that does not have the full alphabet on the front)

Tags: calculator

I am looking for the most advanced scientific calculator capable of as many functions as possible without the calculator having a full 26-letter alphabet on the front (exam requirement).

I have not found anything better than the [Casio fx-991Ex ClassWiz](https://edu.casio.com/products/cwiz/fx991ex/) but surely someone out there has created a more advanced calculator... some sort of portable MATLAB would be ideal.

Functions that would be nice to have: symbolic mathematics, vector calculus (grad, Laplacian, div...)...

Comment: I presume, a touchscreen device is out. How about a calculator with a Russian keyboard.

Comment: As long as the touchscreen isn't too obvious that would be fine. Russian keyboard would probably not be handy as learning Russian is not a negligible task... but thanks for those ideas!